# Haskell - Changing an element at n position? Compilation error?

Tags: haskell

So I have this function

```
listSet :: [a] -> Integer -> a -> [a]
listSet l n x = 
    let (xs,_:ys) = splitAt n l
    xs ++ x : ys
```

But I'm getting an error:

:25:9: parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'

What am I missing to resolve this?

And is my logic correct to split at nth position and adding a element at the beginning of the list?

Any help on the error or on the code would be appreciated!

EDIT: Is there anyway to make this code work without changing Integer to Int?

Comment: A `let` requires an `in`, in this context: `let (xs,_:ys) = splitAt n l in xs ++ x : ys`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes your idea is right - there are just two problems:

- as Jubobs said you need a `in` if you use `let` outside a `do` block, as this is an expression `let ... in ...` (see below)
- you have a slight type problem: `splitAt` want's an `Int`:

---

```
listSet :: [a] -> Int -> a -> [a]
listSet l n x = 
    let (xs,_:ys) = splitAt n l
    in xs ++ x : ys
```

this should work

of course there are a few problems with your solution:

- if `n` is greater than your list your function will fail (example `listSet [1..4] 5 99`)
- the `++` is not very performant for larger lists - and you can do without if you extent on `splitAt`s implementation (see below)

---

as you asked: yes there is an easy way: you can for example just write it in the obvious recursive style - this will even remove the `++` and needed `splitAt`:

```
listSet :: [a] -> Integer -> a -> [a]
listSet [] _ _ = []
listSet (_:xs) 0 y = y:xs
listSet (x:xs) n y = x:listSet xs (n-1) y
```

or you can use your version with the [`genericSplitAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericSplitAt) - but please note the above problems

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work without making it Int and keep it Integer?